# How to store data from service to a class/interface in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

im currently developing a web application and im very new with angular2. I have problem in one of my components. This component act as a form where user can update its data.

I want to access a specific data in my json. The current code i used is to store the data in an object of a class however, i think i have implemented it wrong so it does not reached its desired function. Below is my UserDetailsComponent

**UserDetailsComponents.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ModalDirective } from 'ng2-bootstrap/modal/modal.component';

import { ApiService } from '../../assets/services/api.service';

import { UserDetails } from '../../assets/classes/user-details';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-user-details',
  templateUrl: './user-details.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./user-details.component.scss']
})
export class UserDetailsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

    id: any;
    data: UserDetails;

    private sub: any;

    constructor(
      private route: ActivatedRoute,
      private apiService: ApiService,
      private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
      this.createForm();
      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
        this.id = params['id']; //console.log(this.id);
        this.apiService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(values => 
          this.data = values[0];
         ) 
      })
    }
}
```

And below is my userDetails class

**UserDetails.ts**

```
export class UserDetails {
    id: string;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    status: boolean;
}
```

What i want to do is simply by using `this.data` to access the `id`, `first_name`, `last_name`, `status` within the component.

**Example**

```
createForm(data){
      this.userDetailForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [this.data.id],
        first_name: [this.data.first_name, Validators.required],
        last_name: [this.data.last_name, Validators.required],
        status: [this.data.status, Validators.required]
      });
}
```

Any kind of help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well you are creating the form before retrieving data ;) You need to either create the form after retrieving data or initialize the form (as empty) and then use setValue after receiving data :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to either create the form after retrieving data or initialize the form (as empty) and then use setValue after receiving data :) Here is an example for building the form after retrieving data:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
    this.id = params['id']; //console.log(this.id);
    this.apiService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(values => {
      this.data = values[0];
      this.createForm();  // crete form after retriving data
    }) 
  })
}

createForm(){
      this.userDetailForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [this.data.id],
        first_name: [this.data.first_name, Validators.required],
        last_name: [this.data.last_name, Validators.required],
        status: [this.data.status, Validators.required]
      });
}
```

and then in your template you should set an `*ngIf`, so that the form will not be rendered in the view unless the form is created, so that your app won't throw an error.

```
<form [formGroup]="userDetailForm" *ngIf="userDetailForm">
```

Comment: No problem, glad I could help! Have a nice day and happy coding! :)

Comment: Would you mind if i ask more questions regarding angular2?

Comment: Sure, depends on the questions quite much as well. You have to remember tho that we are all volunteers here on SO, so I'm not accessible all the time, as well as I'm far from a pro, haha :D  But sure I can help if I can. You can reach me on fb: @ajt82

Answer (score 0):

change your ngOnInit method

```
 ngOnInit() {

      this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params =>{
        this.id = params['id']; //console.log(this.id);
        this.apiService.getUserById(this.id).subscribe(values => 
          this.data = values[0];
          this.createForm(this.data);
         ) 
      })
```

and your createForm method as

```
createForm(data){
      this.userDetailForm = this.fb.group({
        id: [data.id],
        first_name: [data.first_name, Validators.required],
        last_name: [data.last_name, Validators.required],
        status: [data.status, Validators.required]
      });
}
```